# How to use the SequoiaDB import tool?

Tags: database, sequoiadb

Is it possible that we import csv files of two different structures into a table according to the conditions?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is ok when you adjust the status in import command field. However, if the structures of two tables are not same, especially in field segmentation, is it  appropriate when you put them in the same table?

Comment: The relationship of two csv. file are just similar to a relational database. For example, one is a product table and the other is classification table. Now these two files are not only two files that we can control. I need to integrate it myself through applying programs. After importing the file, it matches the other file through the relationship and then write to the database, which is in low efficiency.

Comment: In the bank scenarios, we usually import two tables A and B into SequoiaDB first. Then use Sparksql to integrate the A and B tables into the C table of SequoiaDB. The similar statements are as follows:
Insert into C select ... from A left join B on ... where ...

And you can refer to http://doc.sequoiadb.com/cn/SequoiaDB-cat_id-1432190587-edition_id-0